# Using a Java class in the clojure repl

Tags: clojure

I have the following Java class:

```
public class Speak {
   public static String greet() {
     return "Hello! I am a human!";
   }
}
```

I have compiled this to Speak.class

How do I now import it into the clojure repl and how do classpaths and namespaces fit in?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With the standard clojure repl, the class file needs to be available on the classpath used to start the repl.  Here's an example

```
java -cp pathToClojure\clojure.jar;.\src;.\lib;.\lib\* clojure.main %1
```

I have the src included for clojure source, the lib folder included for class files, and lib* included for classes included in jar files.

In this example, the Speak class can be included and used with:

```
user=> (import Speak)
Speak
user=> (Speak/greet)
"Hello! I am a human!"
```

This assumes that you have set up the classpath before starting the repl.  If you want to add something to the classpath after the repl is started it's more complicated. Example code to do it can be found  [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/clojure/AJXqbpGMQw4)

Comment: thanks, how does lein repl allow me to add the classpath at start up?

Comment: leiningen wants all jar files to come from a standard repository for repeatability.  There is a discussion of this at https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/leiningen/DC84wkWDB0c